# JBOSS Hangs when maxThreads limit is reached

Tags: jboss, jvm, struts, jboss5.x, server.xml

I have a Struts 1.3 Application running in JBOSS AS 5.1. We have set 2000 HTTP Threads in the server.xml file for the HTTP Connector and allocated approx 2GB of RAM in the JVM heap to JBOSS in the run.conf file. The system has a total of 4GB RAM and the remaining RAM is in use by other applications.

Whenever my system is hit with over 2000 concurrent requests, Jboss just hangs and stops working. I don't get exceptions on the console or out of memory errors of any sort, it just hangs.

How do I resolve this? Should I put mod_cluster or something in front of JBOSS? Or should I just allocate more threads to the connector, if so how do I figure out what ratio to use between memory and maxThreads on the HTTP connector?

Answer (score 5):

2000 is a very high number. If you truly need it to handle 2000 concurrent requests, you will need to setup multiple instances and distribute the load evenly across the instances. You can setup a load balancer or apache+mod_jk in front of jboss.

How much memory to use will depend on the application. How many instances to use will depend on how well the instances perform under load and whether you can get the required response time.

Comment: Do you mean setup multiple instances on the same system? If so why would that be beneficial over a single instance of JBOSS running? This is an enterprise web app so handling 2000+ users is something we need. Also could you recommend some tool that I could use to figure out how much memory each component of my application is using?

Comment: @user1266369 You don't need 2000 connector threads to handle 2000 users. Unless the application makes _very_ heavy network use, 200 is probably more realistic. For greater throughput, more RAM / heap space will help and there are numerous ways to tune the connector for better performance.

Comment: If its an enterprise web app, you dont want one instance serving all the users. What happens when that single instance goes down ? Failover is definitely one reason to setup multiple instances. Also, if the cpu usage on that one servers grows, you can always stand up another server and move the second instance to that server.

Comment: The tools I have used for analyze memory usage for Sun JDK are verbosegc log files, jconsole and sometimes visualvm. But I dont think they provide the details you have requested.

Comment: @Mikaveli As far as I know every new URL hit for my web app that hits my JBOSS service will be handled in a new HTTP connector thread until a previous thread is released. If there is a lot of concurrent traffic on the web app this forces the system to use more threads from the connector as far as my understanding goes. How are you making 200 threads work for 2000 users in this case?

Comment: @Kevin I have used visualvm but there seems to be too much data in there to really zero in on which of my classes is using more memory to come up with a proper ratio of something along the lines of 1thread per y mb of memory in heap.

Comment: We used mod_cluster which is supposed to be the new load balancer over mod_jk yesterday in front of JBOSS but seem to experience the same issue with the HTTPD server. When I am hitting HTTPD server with more than the MaxClients parameter's value using Jmeter it too seems to hang just like JBOSS. My test httpd config for maxclients was: ServerLimit 20, MaxClients 500, MinSpareThreads 25, MaxSpareThreads 75, ThreadsPerChild 25.

Comment: If you expect 2000 concurrent connections, you will need to set MaxClients to the same number ; or ideally even higher.

Comment: @user1266369 That's not how it works, imagine connectors more like a lane on a motorway / freeway. The vehicles represent the requests to your application (scripts, images, dynamic data etc) - whilst the user may be using the app, minute pauses between requests and operations allow other users to utilise the same connector.

Comment: @Mikaveli My web app isn't a website so there are no images etc. It's simple in terms of URL hits our app, we write request to DB or process it accordingly in terms of struts action classes doing their work. When we run  a load test with JMeter with 2000 threads until I set my HTTP connector to that value or greater it doesn't seem to process all the load.

Comment: @Kevin true the 500 was just a test scenario. However, why is it hanging? Is it because I have not allocated enough memory i.e. do I have too many MaxClients than HTTPD can support with the system memory that is available?

Comment: When MaxClients is reached, it will say so in the log files. Regarding memory usage, you will really need to monitor your system to find out.